# How can i achieve exact functionality like pointerlock example in threejs but move around programmatically instead of mouse

Tags: three.js

How can i achieve [THREE.js pointerlock controls example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html) functionality but move around programmatically (values from accelerometer device) instead of mouse movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[THREE.PointerLockControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js) (next: *Module*) works this way:

- *Module* makes a construction *yawObject -> pitchObject -> camera* (*pitchObject* is a child of *yawObject* and *camera* becomes a child of *pitchObject*).
- You add *yawObject* (which you could get from *Module* with `yourControls.getObject()` function) to your scene (to keep transforms updated).
- *Module* adds *'mousemove'* event listener and updates *yawObject.rotation.y* and *pitchObject.rotation.x* when you move mouse if **`yourControls.enabled !== false`**.
- Next if you are interested in actually locking cursor you could do it in your client code as in [example](http://threejs.org/examples/?q=pointe#misc_controls_pointerlock).
- And to update your camera position you could manipulate *yawObject's* position (`yourControls.getObject().position`).

So to manipulate controls without mouse you could setup *Module* this way:

```
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0); // THREE.PointerLockControls does this too

var myControls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);

var controlsObject = myControls.getObject();

controlsObject.position.set(myEntryX, myEntryY, myEntryZ); // set starting point
controlsObject.rotation.y = myEntryYaw; // rotate yaw obj
controlsObject.children[0].rotation.x = myEntryPitch; // rotate pitch obj

scene.add(controlsObject);
```

and then keeping `myControls.enabled = false` manipulate `controlsObject.position`, `controlsObject.rotation.y`, `controlsObject.children[0].rotation.x`.